# ASP dot net mvc - Add item to list not working, It does nothing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms, model, controller

I'm making a webapplication with ASP.net mvc. You can see the recipes at : /recipe

The problem is when I add a recipe at /recipe/create it does not work. I want it to show on the /recipe page. [Recipe Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0ToH.png)

So I think there is something wrong in the controller or the view, but I think it's the controller.

Here is the recipeController code :

```
 public class RecipeController : Controller
{
    List<RecipeViewModel> vm = new List<RecipeViewModel>();

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        foreach (var recept in MockDataRecipeFactory.GetRecipes())
        {
            vm.Add(new RecipeViewModel
            {
                Id = recept.Id,
                Name = recept.Name,
                Category = recept.Category,
                NumberOfIngredients = recept.Ingredients.Count
            });
        }
        return View(vm);
    }

    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Create(RecipeViewModel recipemodel)
    {
        vm.Add(new RecipeViewModel
        {
            Name = recipemodel.Name,
            Id = recipemodel.Id,
            Category = recipemodel.Category,
            NumberOfIngredients = recipemodel.NumberOfIngredients
        });

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

What I do is, I have a list of RecipeViewModel at the top, and add the created item to that list.

Here is the RecipeViewModel :

```
    public class RecipeViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Naam")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Categorie")]
    public RecipeCategory Category { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Aantal")]
    public int NumberOfIngredients { get; set; }
}
```

And here is the form in the view:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
    <form asp-action="Create">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Id">Id:</label>
            <input asp-for="Id" type="text" class="form-control" name="id" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Name">Naam:</label>
            <input asp-for="Name" type="text" class="form-control" name="name" />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Category">Categorie</label>
            <select class="form-control" asp-for="Category">
                <option value="0">none</option>
                <option value="0">Cake</option>
                <option value="0">Desert</option>
                <option value="0">Sidedish</option>
                <option value="0">Maincourse</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="NumberOfIngredients">Aantal</label>
            <input asp-for="NumberOfIngredients" type="number" class="form-control" name="number" />
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Voeg toe</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

So when I add a recipe, it goes back to the recipe page, but it does not show the added recipe. What do I do wrong? [Create Recipe Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPu79.png)

Comment: Probably doesn't have anything to do with your problem, but is it on purpose that all your Category `option`s have `value="0"`?

Comment: Are you sure that it is even adding it to the list in the controller? Try adding one then adding another one but put a breakpoint on the controller before you add the second one. See if the first has been added

Comment: @Rafalon I forgot to change it :),

Comment: @JamesS Yes it does actually add to the list, but the index page does nothing with it

Comment: @TheProgrammer I'd probably have a look at HenkHoterman 's answer below. The issue is probably because it's not a static list and so it resets every time the controller is called

Comment: @JamesS Yes it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class RecipeController : Controller
{
    List<RecipeViewModel> vm = new List<RecipeViewModel>();
```

Your `vm` list is an instance field. The controller and the list will be created again on each request.

For a simple (demo) solution, make it static:

```
static List<RecipeViewModel> vm = new List<RecipeViewModel>();
```

this is not thread-safe and not suitable for production anyway. But you should be able to testdrive it.

Comment: It does work! Thank you! But what would be the better way of doing it? I am curious :)

Comment: A database is the normal store. Depends on how long you want to keep your data.

Comment: Ah okay, yea I first want to learn it without a database. Then later add one :)